# How do I track the number of windows being opened in chrome in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to write a chrome extension that says "how is your day" when you open a new tab, and when you open more than five tabs, it says stop opening tabs. How do I track the number of tabs open in a window in Chrome? The closest I have found is chrome.tabs.query, but I am not sure how to use it to track the number of tabs. Any advice is helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `chrome.tabs.query`?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't find a function to track the amount of open tabs. Did I miss something?